# Вместо значения "None"

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Вот, я написал такой код:

```py
class QuestionModal(disnake.ui.Modal):
    def __init__(self):
        components = [
            disnake.ui.TextInput(
                label="Вопрос",
                placeholder="Какой вопрос вы хотите создать?",
                custom_id="question",
                style=TextInputStyle.short,
                max_length=50,
            ),
        ]
        super().__init__(
            title="Создание вопроса",
            custom_id="create_question",
            components=components,
        )

    async def callback(self, inter: disnake.ModalInteraction):
        question = inter.data.get("question")

        embed = disnake.Embed(description=f"``{question}``", timestamp=datetime.datetime.now(), color=0x1c00ed)
        embed.set_author(name=f"Вопрос от {inter.user.display_name}:", icon_url=inter.user.display_avatar.url)
        embed.set_footer(text=inter.user.id)

        channel = bot.get_channel(1123870384916275232)
        await channel.send(embed=embed)

@bot.slash_command()
async def tags(inter: disnake.AppCmdInter):
    await inter.response.send_modal(modal=QuestionModal())
```

Почему-то вместо question возвращает None, не знаю что делать.

Comment: У функций нет `return`